# Cygwin - gcc does not find include files

Tags: cygwin

When compiling LLVM 3.3 under Cygwin, g++ does not find the appropriate header files, although they are surely present.

`$ make --trace`

`g++ -I/cygdrive/c/llvm-3.3.src/include -I/cygdrive/c/llvm-3.3.src/lib/Support  -D_DEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -Woverloaded-virtual -Wcast-qual    -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -c -MMD -MP -MF "/cygdrive/c/llvm-3.3.src/lib/Support/Release+Asserts/APFloat.d.tmp" -MT "/cygdrive/c/llvm-3.3.src/lib/Support/Release+Asserts/APFloat.o" -MT "/cygdrive/c/llvm-3.3.src/lib/Support/Release+Asserts/APFloat.d" APFloat.cpp -o /cygdrive/c/llvm-3.3.src/lib/Support/Release+Asserts/APFloat.o`

`fatal error: 'llvm/ADT/APFloat.h' file not found`

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably running g++ from your MinGW installation. Check if it's in the PATH with `which g++`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use cygdrive in -I for Mingw gcc. Need to use -IC:/llvm-3.3.src/include.

Details at: http://www.mingw.org/node/45